# How do I keep a variable from updating after setting it?

Tags: c#, list

I have a method for swapping 2 Items in a list. The problem is that the 'temp' variable updates after I change the value of itemA. How do I prevent 'temp' from updating after I initialize it?

```
void SwapItems(Item itemA, Item itemB)
{
    Item temp = itemA;

    itemA.OriginItemPosition = itemB.OriginItemPosition;
    itemA.OriginItemRectangle = itemB.OriginItemRectangle;

    itemB.OriginItemPosition = temp.OriginItemPosition;
    itemB.OriginItemRectangle = temp.OriginItemRectangle;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because temp1 holds the reference of itemA, and not it's values copied.
To swap items in your case I would do:

```
void SwapItems(Item itemA, Item itemB)
{
    var temp1 = itemA.OriginItemPosition;
    var temp2 = itemA.OriginItemRectangle;

    itemA.OriginItemPosition = itemB.OriginItemPosition;
    itemA.OriginItemRectangle = itemB.OriginItemRectangle;

    itemB.OriginItemPosition = temp1;
    itemB.OriginItemRectangle = temp2;
}
```

You could also have something like this, which some may find nicer:

```
// Swaps the references themselves for reference-types.
void Swap<T>(ref T a, ref T b)
{
    var tmp = a;
    a = b;
    b = tmp;
}

// Swaps the properties between two Item objects.
void SwapItems(Item a, Item b)
{
    Swap(ref a.OriginalItemPosition, ref b.OriginalItemPosition);
    Swap(ref a.OriginalItemRectangle, ref b.OriginalItemRectangle);
}
```

Comment: So after the discussion about not needlessly creating object you propose a solution that will incur boxing? At least make it generic.

Comment: +1 Nicely done, although none of this is needed to simply swap list items, but this could have use if other references to these objects also need to "swap" silently.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth True. If he wants to swap items in the list he can use `Swap(list[a], list[b])` or something. It seemed, however, he was struggling with the idea of reference-types and temp values swapping.

Comment: That generic swap method wouldn't work.  You're swapping the parameter references but not the referenced values.  They would have to be `ref` parameters.

Comment: @JeffMercado You're right, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to swap two items in a `List`, don't do it by swapping the values of properties on the items (unless you have a good reason). Do it by swapping the items in the list. This way if you e.g. add more properties to your items, you don't have to modify the swap method to copy them all.

```
static void Swap<T>(IList<T> list, int indexA, int indexB)
{
    int tmp = list[indexA];
    list[indexA] = list[indexB];
    list[indexB] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also implement [ICLoneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx) on Item an then

```
Item temp = itemA.Clone();
```

Comment: @Adam It would be reasonable to assume that this is just the replacement for the original assignment of `temp`.

Comment: @Adam : no swapping but prevents temp to change when updating itemA, that is the point of the thread, no ?

Comment: This assumes a correct implementation of `ICloneable` though, which is tantamount to not bothering with the `ICloneable` interface at all in my opinion. Either way, I've redacted my previous comment and I'm not the downvoter.